# run-clang-tidy is a broken symlink in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, clang

I found that the `run-clang-tidy` script is a broken symlink in Ubuntu 21.10:

```
$ run-clang-tidy
bash: run-clang-tidy: command not found

$ cd /usr/bin

$ ls -l *tidy*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 28 10:13 clang-tidy -> ../lib/llvm-13/bin/clang-tidy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Oct  3 20:38 clang-tidy-13 -> ../lib/llvm-13/bin/clang-tidy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Sep 28 10:13 clang-tidy-diff -> clang-tidy-diff-13.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 45 Oct  3 20:38 clang-tidy-diff-13.py -> ../lib/llvm-13/share/clang/clang-tidy-diff.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 28 10:13 run-clang-tidy -> run-clang-tidy-13.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Oct  3 20:38 run-clang-tidy-13 -> ../lib/llvm-13/bin/run-clang-tidy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Oct  3 20:38 run-clang-tidy-13.py -> ../lib/llvm-13/share/clang/run-clang-tidy

$ ls -l run-clang-tidy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 28 10:13 run-clang-tidy -> run-clang-tidy-13.py

$ ls -l run-clang-tidy-13.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41 Oct  3 20:38 run-clang-tidy-13.py -> ../lib/llvm-13/share/clang/run-clang-tidy

$ ls -l ../lib/llvm-13/share/clang/run-clang-tidy
ls: cannot access '../lib/llvm-13/share/clang/run-clang-tidy': No such file or directory
```

This is happening in a docker container but I assume it's the same in a regular installation. From my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.10
...
RUN \
    apt-get update; \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
        afl++ \
        busybox \
        clang-tidy \
...
```

I can't just use `run-clang-tidy-13` instead because it's run from a makefile that is also used in older Ubuntu versions that don't have `run-clang-tidy-13` (but `run-clang-tidy-12` or earlier).

I can fix it with the following lines in the Dockerfile (or by running the same commands in the container):

```
RUN rm /usr/bin/run-clang-tidy
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/run-clang-tidy-13 /usr/bin/run-clang-tidy
```

but of course that's just an ugly workaround.

Did anyone encounter the same problem? Is there a more elegant solution, other than hoping for a fix in 21.10.1?

For the record (executed in the container):

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu3-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu3-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish

$ clang-tidy --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 13.0.0
  
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: skylake
```